# how to check whether a signal is obtained in every 1 min to a module in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I am trying to do module programming. The logic is that there will be a central device and 2 sub devices in a network. The sub devices will send a signal to the central device every 1 min. If you are receiving a signal from one of the sub device in 1 min then the status of that device will be noted Active. Again after 1 min central device must again search for the signal from that device. If it is not getting that signal within 1 min, then the status of that particular device should be Deactive.

I was trying to implement this in python. But am not getting the idea how to check separately for the signal alerts every 1 min from different sub devices.

When I researched, it's showing I have to use the concepts of multi threading and sleep timers. Can Somebody could kindly suggest me an idea how this can be done?

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The devices are on a network, which means you can use Sockets for communication between your devices. Read [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html) for more details on using Sockets in python. Using Sockets, you can continuously listen to signals received from sub-devices and just update the device state every minute.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
import threading
import thread

def recieve_message(ip):
    threading.Timer(60.0, recieve_message).start()
    recieve_message_content

if __name__ == "__main__":
     # Create two threads as follows
     try:
        thread.start_new_thread( recieve_message, (127.0.0.1) )
        thread.start_new_thread( recieve_message, (127.0.0.1) )
     except:
        print "Error: unable to start thread"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.                                     But here if the sub device is not sending the message, how can I get an error !!!

Comment: You put this part in recieve_message_content. there you check if the sub device is active or deactive. than he will try again after 60 seconds. if you want to exit from the function just put return.

Answer (score 0):

What you might need is a multi-client server that works on every message from a group of simultanously connected clients. One easy concept comes from the module `SocketServer`. You have to make a subclass of the Request Handler in order to tell the server what to do with your incoming messages.

*Server*:

```
import SocketServer

PORT = xxxxx    # Any port you desire

class RequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler) :
def handle(self) :
    address = self.client_address()[0]

    time_0 = time.time()
    while True :
        try :
            buff = self.request.recv(1024)
            time_1 = time.time()
            self.request.send("Okay")
        except SocketServer.socket.error :
            print addr, ">> Connection Failure"
            return

        if time_1 - time_0 > 61 :
            print addr, ">> Timeout"
            return

        # Now do something with the buffer
        # ...

server = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer(('', PORT), RequestHandler)
server.server_forever()
```

You could even put the `server.serve_forever()` in a distinguished thread to be sure your commands following after reading the buffer won't take too long and do nothing with your buffer inside the request handling. So you would have one thread listening to your Ethernet Port and writing to the buffer and another one that reads from this buffer and processes the data.

You can read this buffer when you make it an attribute of the class or use a global variable.

*Client*:

```
import socket
import time

IP = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    # The IP of the server
PORT = xxxxx            # Same port on which the server is listening

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((IP, PORT))

while True :
    time.sleep(60.0)

    try :
        sock.send("Some crazy message")
        buff = sock.recv(1024)

        if buff != "Okay" :
            print "Something went wrong"
            return
    except socket.error :
        print "Connection Failure"
        break
```

PS: I did not test this code... So no guarantee!...